# Web map services displaying poorly

Tags: windows-7, webserver

Web map services no longer display correctly in ArcGIS and Google Earth - no one else on network is experiencing these.  Using windows 7 OS.  These problem began abruptly  (1 day they were working, the next they were not).  Specific problems include not displaying at all; correct display on 10% of the monitor and repeating lines of coloured squiggles and text on the remaining 90%; and small, widely spaced, pixels in place of colour fill.

Links where this occurs:

arcgis

http://wms.ess-ws.nrcan.gc.ca/wms/toporama_en

Google earth

http://openmaps.gov.bc.ca/kml/BCGov_Web_Map_Library.kml

I can't pinpoint any changes to the computer setup which may have prompted this, however, adding arcgis 10.1 SP 1 occured around the same time.  Probably just a coincidence.

Anyone had similar problems?  or solutions to these?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by uninstalling Kaspersky, reinstalling, updating Kaspersky's database and rebooting.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was:  Closing Kaspersky Internet Security 2012 allowed all Web Map Services to display correctly.  Restarting the software restarted the problem.  Have been unable to determine why and so have posted queries to Kaspersky.

Thanks!
Jim